# Should questions be marked as duplicates if the issue is based on the same principles?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

Today I marked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543171/a-callback-function-doesnt-work-in-an-asynchronous-call as a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (Actually the OP asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542292/how-to-return-result-of-function) earlier, and I had closed it as duplicate).

As it is clear both the questions are regarding handling the value returned by an asynchronous method call in JavaScript. Now is that enough to mark it as duplicate? Was I right in doing so?

Also even after marking it as duplicate I had tried to offer some help to OP by suggesting some code snippets in JSFiddle.

Now the OP is again asking to reopen the question since their issue is not resolved. How should these sorts of cases be handled?

Comment: I linked the OP to your meta-question.

Comment: In my first post you answered that I need to implement callback and closed topic. And I implemented callback, but nothing changed. I was forced to create a new topic, because then no one comes to indoor.

Comment: There is a practical limit to what can be accomplished in Q+A.  The OP needs a brain transplant to get ahead, we can't help him get one.  This is a job for a teacher.

Comment: @bob why would there be any difference between returning in the first async call (under `VK.Api.call`) and returning in the anonymous function passed to `getFriends`? You essentially moved the return statement to another place; that won't fix the problem. If you read and took the time to fully understand the canonical your first post was marked as a duplicate of, you wouldn't've had to ask a second question—I assure it.

Comment: Is it wrong to say that  questions should describe _symptoms_. But duplicates are based on the _cause_ ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue in their question *is* directly related to them attempting to return a value from an asynchronous callback function in JavaScript. The duplicate rightly explains that it is impossible for the OP to do exactly what they want (i.e. running an asynchronous function as if it was synchronous).

If they are not able to solve their problem given the detailed and precise question they were linked to, that should not be our problem. We do not have an obligation to do their work for them, and any answer to the OP's question would just rehash what was stated in the canonical question.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295617/should-questions-be-marked-as-duplicates-if-the-issue-is-based-on-the-same-princ#comment200289_295617

Comment: If it's impossible why he told me 'you need to use a callback method'?

Comment: @bob: it is impossible to do *exactly* as you asked (i.e. `friends === list` immediately upon assignment). One common workaround is to structure your application to use callbacks so that this is not necessary, but this requires all of your asynchronous code to use callbacks. You might want to read the duplicate question linked more closely which explains this in more detail.

Comment: @bob, it is frequently good idea to type your question into search box of your favorite search engine first. I.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+why+need+to+use+a+callback+method will give you link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070495/why-use-callback-in-javascript-what-are-its-advantages. At that point you should have enough information to either get answer to your question OR prepared to ask much better question than you'd do otherwise.